# How to check if the batch pool nodes are idle in data factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch, azure-sdk

I am using a Python code that creates the batch pool using the Azure SDK for Python. I have deployed this code in function apps and I am using it in data factory to create the batch pool. I want to check if the nodes have started or if they are in idle state before I run the rest of components in the pipeline. Is there any way I can check this in data factory?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way can check it in Data Factory. Data Factory will call and run the Azure function directly.

Comment: Is there any way to check using the Python script after creating the resources?

Comment: @Sindu_ It sounds achievable. Data Factory pipeline may like this: Azure function-->python.  Function active to create the batch pool and python active to check if the nodes have started.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is no direct way to check the node status via ADF. But you can consider below workaround to achieve the same via ADF using Web Activity.

- **Step 1:** Make an API to call Azure Batch services to get to your node
  status details. We can leverage web activity in Azure data factory
  to do the same.
- **Step 2:** Based on response from Step 1, Invoke execution of your
  pipeline further activities.

Check below links to know more details about [Batch Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/compute-node/get) and [Web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)